# loop deleting the last character

Tags: vba, loops, excel, for-loop

In VBA I am trying to loop through a range and delete the last character of the text of every cell.

I understand the code to delete the last character of text in a cell is as follows:
    myString = Left(myString, Len(myString) - 1)

However I am trying to get this to work in a for loop and i just get error message object required. Its probably something obvious I am missing.

Here is my code with the For Loop:

```
Dim rngh As Range, cellh As Range
Dim myString As String
Set rngh = Range("H1:H500")
For Each cellh In rngh
    myString = cellh.Text
    myString = Left(myString, Len(myString) - 1)
Next cellh
```

Thanks.

Comment: What is `rngh`? Is it `Rng`?

Comment: rngh is the variable name for the allocated range i want to go through.

Comment: So my thinking is select the cell in the range. select the text in that cell. Then remove the last character.

Comment: Which line do you receive the error on when debugging? I'm guessing that it's because the `LEFT` function is being used on some empty cells.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't use .Text or loop one cell at a time as it will be slower - use an array:

```
Dim vData
Dim n                     As Long
vData = Range("H1:H500").Value
For n = 1 To UBound(vData, 1)
    If Len(vData(n, 1)) <> 0 Then vData(n, 1) = Left$(vData(n, 1), Len(vData(n, 1)) - 1)
Next n
Range("H1:H500").Value = vData
```

for example.

Comment: Works perfectly thank you! I will look to use arrays more often in the future!

Answer (score 0):

You've got an error in the set line. I think it should be

`Set rngh = Range("H1:H500")`

But there will be exceptions when you try to shorten empty strings. You must check if it's possible to do this .. something like

```
myString = cellh.Text
If Len(myString) > 0 Then
    myString = Left(myString, Len(myString) - 1)
End If
```

Comment: Well spotted, it was just a typo though it still doesn't work :(

Comment: I'm sorry, forgot to add the check for empty strings .. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Dim rngh As Range, cellh As Range
    Dim myString As String
    Set rngh = Range("H1:H500")
    For Each cellh In rngh
        If Not IsEmpty(cellh) Then
            myString = cellh.Text
            myString = Left(myString, Len(myString) - 1)
            cellh.Value = myString
        End If
    Next cellh
```